# To good to be true? headphone content

Tags: headphones, sony

hey, 
ive been looking at some headphone suggestions here and a lot seem to recommend the Sony MDR-7506

i found them new for $50 including postage, but are they fake?

it says they are in australia but all the others in australia range from $100 - $200.

cheers
Jamie

Comment: Is there a full refund policy or a warranty? I'd go for it if that's the case. Otherwise, what is that - 2 or 3 hours worth of salary?

Comment: a lil more when your an un employed student :p

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if somebody was selling it for that.  I bought mine new a long time ago for $80 (have since been destroyed), so it doesn't seem too far fetched.

Comment: yer true, i mean i didnt think it was too cheap, but just that the others in AUS are so expensive compared to this.
the feedback is good for these though so.

Answer (score 1):

Fakes come in all shapes and sizes and I've bought fake Sony headphones in the past.. from a store. Fake microphones from established brands/models do [exist](http://homerecording.about.com/od/microphones101/a/Fake_Shure_Mics.htm) too on Ebay. Maybe add salt in proportion to how good the deal is? Request high-res photos from the seller and look at the details?

Comment: good idea, i already asked if they were genuine. but ill do this too
thanks


Answer (score 1):

I dunno if I'd trust it.  I bought some fake Neutrik connectors (didn't have a hologram) from Amazon.